# SpireKit 2D set main menu

Tags: objective-c, macos, sprite-kit

Today, I have made a new SpireKit Game, but I have one problem before I set the app in the App Store.

I am looking for how to set a mainmenu. In the main menu you see some buttons .. such as 'Play!' .. How to do that? I have searched on Google but I can't found anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you read up more on SKScene transitioning...[good tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/42699/spritekit-tutorial-for-beginners)

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Transitions/Transitions.html